# How would I parse all of the data from a paged API at once in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm making an app with a tableview and search controller using the rick and morty API, https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/. The API is paged and I'm able to parse the data from the first page and display it to my tableview. I'm also able get the other pages of the API when I scroll through the tableview. I can't seem to figure out how to parse all the data from the pages at once. When I use the search controller I can't search for all the characters, until I scroll through the tableView to get all of the characters. I want to be able to search for any character without having to scroll through the tableView first. How would I parse all the data from the different pages at once and display the data to the tableview? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

This is my current code for parsing the data and getting the other pages when scrolling through the tableView

```
func getIntitalRickAndMortyData(){
    downloadedDataArray = []
    //here first page is next page
    nextPageUrl = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/"
    getRickAndMortyData()
    filteredCharacterArray = downloadedDataArray
}

func getRickAndMortyData() {

    //construct the url, use guard to avoid nonoptional
    guard let urlObj = URL(string: nextPageUrl) else
    { return }

    //fetch data
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj) {[weak self](data, response, error) in

        //to avoid non optional in JSONDecoder
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            //decode object
            let downloadedRickAndMorty = try JSONDecoder().decode(PagedCharacters.self, from: data)
            self?.downloadedDataArray.append(contentsOf: downloadedRickAndMorty.results)
            self?.nextPageUrl = downloadedRickAndMorty.info.next
            self?.filteredCharacterArray = (self?.downloadedDataArray)!
            self?.currentPage += 1

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            //print(self?.aryDownloadedData as Any)

        } catch {
            print(error)

        }

        }.resume()

}
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let count = self.downloadedDataArray.count
        if count > 1 {
        let lastElement = count - 1
        if indexPath.row == lastElement {
            //call get api for next page
            getRickAndMortyData()
        }
    }

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rickandmortyCell") as? CharacterTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    let results: Results
    if isFiltering() {
        results = filteredCharacterArray[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        results = downloadedDataArray[indexPath.row]
    }


    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    cell.nameLabel.text = results.name
    cell.statusLabel.text = results.status
    cell.genderLabel.text = results.gender
    cell.originLabel.text = results.origin.name
    cell.lastlocationLabel.text = results.location.name

    let id = String(results.id)
    cell.idLabel.text = id



    return cell
}
```

}

I've tried doing it using a while loop and keeping a current page count and incrementing it, but nothing displays and I get this in my console "XPC connection interrupted"

```
 func getAllRickAndMortyData() {
    while currentPage <= 25 {
        getRickAndMortyData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question should include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You've included almost 200 lines of code with a pretty vague question. The more specificity you can include in your question the more likely you are to get a useful response. (e.g., _I have done x and I am stuck at y, I tried z but it didn't work, how do I solve n?_)

Comment: Sorry about that. I've tried to reword the question better. Please let me know if should change or add anything else.

Comment: I think you should still include minimal and relevant example code. In this case you're asking "How do I parse all the data from all the pages at once?" but you haven't explained what you've tried so far to answer your own question or where you are stuck. Bad questions ask broadly to have concepts explained. Good questions are narrow, show what you've tried, and explain where you're stuck. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "How would I parse all the data from the different pages at once and display the data to the tableview?" Can you elaborate a little bit more on the question and why do you need to do that? Is there something specific you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: When I use the search controller I can't search for all the characters, until I scroll through the tableView to get all of the characters. I want to be able to search for any character without having to scroll through the tableView first.